# Malayalam fonts not showing in opencart 3 invoice pdf

Tags: php, twig, tcpdf, opencart-3

I am new to opencart. I am using journal 3 theme for my opencart3 website. I am using malayalam font(an Indian language) in my website, which is working fine. But, when look into the pdf invoice, malayalam font is not showing. The pdf invoice extension uses tcpdf to make pdf. Please help me to resolve this issue. [this is my pdf view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of3iG.png)

This is the code in twig

```
<tr>
   <td width="120"><b>{{ text_payment_method }}</b></td>
   <td>{{ order['payment_method'] }}</td>
</tr>
```

This is the code in pdfinvoice extension

```
$data['order']['payment_method'] = strip_tags($data['order']['payment_method']);
```

Comment: which pdf library used in opencart website. DOMPDF,TCPDF or FPDF ??

Comment: OR use pdf invoice Extension ??